# How can I organize this set of data into a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

It's been a little while since I've done anything making a database so I was wondering if someone could help me out in organizing some data.  This is what I have:

- (X) TEAMS

  - (X) Players

    - (1) Name
    - (X) Playable Positions (positions can be played by any player on any team)
    - (X) Player Manager (can manager any player on any team)
    - (X) Player Trainer (can train any player on any team)
    - (X) Player Teacher (can teach any player on any team)

      - (1) Subject
      - (1) Years been teaching

Ideally I would put this into a simple MySQL DB but if there's another way/medium to organize this please let me know, I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **rough design**:  (you might have to modify db according to your requirements)

```
tblTeams
------------------------------
team_id    | int    | primary key
team_name  | varchar| not null

tblPositions
-----------------------------
position_id| int    | primary key
pos_name   | varchar|

tblPlayers
------------------------------
player_id  | int    | primary key
player_name| varchar
team_id    | int    | foreign key tblTeams(team_id)

tblManagers
-----------------------------
manager_id | int    | primary key
name       | varchar

tblManager_mapping
-----------------------------
id         | int    | primary key
manager_id | int    | foreign key tblManagers(manager_id)
player_id  | int    | foreign key tblPlayers(player_id)

tblSubjects 
----------------------------
sub_id     | int    | primary key
sub_name   | varchar

tblTeachers
-----------------------------
teacher_id | int    | primary key
name       | varchar

tblTeacher_player_mapping
-----------------------------
id         | int    | primary key
teacher_id | int    | foreign key tblTeachers(teacher_id)
player_id  | int    | foreign key tblPlayers(player_id)

tblTeacher_subject_mapping
-----------------------------
id         | int    | primary key
teacher_id | int    | foreign key tblTeachers(teacher_id)
sub_id     | int    | foreign key tblSubjects(sub_id)
teaching_since| date
```

**EDIT:**
Added new table as you clarified one player can have multiple positions. (also removed `position_id` from `tblPlayers`)

```
tblPlayers_position
-----------------------------
mapping_id | int    | primary key
player_id  | int    | foreign key tblPlayers(player_id)
position_id| int    | foreign key tblPositions(position_id)
```

Comment: Not sure you had the whole understanding of my data, each player is unique to one team but positions, managers, teachers, and trainers are not unique to one player and one player may have multiple positions, managers, teachers, and trainers.  Also, each player has a unique name and each teacher has a unique subject and year (which I know doesn't make sense in real life).  This does give me a good staring place though so thank you for that.  I was hoping to have less tables but I might just have to have an object table and a mapping table for each.

Comment: From Your Comments: *each player is unique to one team* "yes I did it." *but positions, managers, teachers, and trainers are not unique to one player and one player may have multiple positions, managers, teachers, and trainers* "Among these, I corrected positions see updated answer."

Comment: *each player has a unique name and each teacher has a unique subject and year (which I know doesn't make sense in real life)* "That constrains you can apply from your side I guess :)". *This does give me a good staring place though so thank you for that.* "You are welcome.." *I was hoping to have less tables but I might just have to have an object table and a mapping table for each.* "Less tables will lead to poorly normalized database design and will have many issues while coding.